# In production (deployed to pythonanywhere.com) - How do I resolve this error while adding user to group in django admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, pythonanywhere

Everything work in my local environment but gives error in production.

I'm using **Django 3.0.4, Postgresql 11.8, Python 3.7**

**Here's my custom permission in a decorator.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = []
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            
            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view the page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

**Then in my view.py:**

```
@login_required
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['supervisor'])
def journal_entry(request):
    JournalFormset = modelformset_factory(JournalEntry, fields='__all__', extra=1)
    

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JournalFormset(request.POST, queryset=JournalEntry.objects.none())
        instance = form.save()
    
    form = JournalFormset(queryset=JournalEntry.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'journal_entry.html', {'form':form})
```

**When I try to add the a user to 'supervisor' group as in picture below:**

[adding  user to 'supervisor' group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbS0f.jpg)

**I get the following error:**

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/auth/user/2/change/
syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...ser_groups" ("user_id", "group_id") VALUES (2, 1) ON CONFLIC...
                                                             ^
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://mogononso.pythonanywhere.com/admin/auth/user/2/change/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...ser_groups" ("user_id", "group_id") VALUES (2, 1) ON CONFLIC...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /home/mogononso/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 86
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['/home/mogononso/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/git/ext/gitdb',
 '/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/mogononso/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/mogononso/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/mogononso/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/mogononso/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/home/mogononso/churchapp/churchapp2',
 '/home/mogononso/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gitdb/ext/smmap']
Server time:    Tue, 7 Jul 2020 16:07:26 +0000
```

I have tried:

1. running python manage.py makemigrations & migrate commands
2. I created a separate database in production - same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Django 3 requires a more recent version of Postgres than the one that you're likely to be using on PythonAnywhere. Contact PA support about the issue so we can discuss migrating you to a newer version of Postgres.

Comment: Thanks, I'll reach out.